# Compilar Apk Android Cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova, compilação

Quando tento compilar, a seguinte mensagem é retornada:

Mas acontece que está tudo instalado, GitHub, SDK Android, Java, Node.js
Configurei as Variáveis de ambiente no PATH, criei as variáveis  "ANDROID_HOME" e "JAVA_HOME"

e na hora que mando netbeans limpar e construir, ele me retorna esses erros

C:\comandaAPP\nbproject\build.xml:285: The following error occurred while executing this line: (
que é representado por essa linha abaixo:
    **< ant dir="platforms/android" target="clean"/ >**

E outro erro em:
**C:\comandaAPP\platforms\android\build.xml:97:**

Cannot find **C:\Arquivos de programas\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml imported from C:\comandaAPP\platforms\android\build.xm**l

representado por essa linha:
   **< import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" / >**

O que ocorre é que eu não sei de onde ele tá encontrando essa pasta em arquivos de programas, já que a variavel de ambiente ANDROID_HOME está configurada em C:\Android-sdk

Comment: Não sei de onde é tirado esse caminho em arquivos de programas

Comment: Qual o significado disso  ant dir="platforms/android" target="clean"

Comment: está querendo dizer o a pasta "plataforms" está dentro da pasta ANT ?